# Microsoft Access form submission

Tags: ms-access

I'm new to Access and have a few questions. To start off, after watching some tutorials and researching, I keep getting a Syntax error on my submission button. I am just trying to write to the database from the form. Here is my error.

```
Private Sub btn_Add_Click()
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO IPA_Raw_Data(Date, Auditor) " _
    " VALUES(" & Me.txt_Date & ",'" & Me.txt_Name & "')"

btn_Clear_Click
End Sub
```

I'm sure it's something simple. Just new to this. Thanks!

Comment: Is `IPA_Raw_Data` a query? If so, what is it's SQL?

Comment: I was able to fix that with the corrected answer below. I need some help with syntax for my combobox. I keep getting an error now. `Private Sub btn_Add_Click()

    CurrentDb.Execute _
        "INSERT INTO IPA_Raw_Data([Date], Auditor, Line_Clearance) " & _
        "VALUES (#" & Format(Me!txt_Date.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#,'" & Me!txt_Name.Value & "','" & Me!cb_LC.Value & "')"
        
    btn_Clear_Click`

Comment: If `Line_Clearance` is numeric, remove the single quotes wrapping `cb_LC`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Date* is a reserved word in SQL, and your syntax needs a brush-up. So:

```
Private Sub btn_Add_Click()

    CurrentDb.Execute _
        "INSERT INTO IPA_Raw_Data([Date], Auditor) " & _
        "VALUES (#" & Format(Me!txt_Date.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#,'" & Me!txt_Name.Value & "')"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing the date up, kinda assumed the date was an issue, also now after running that, I get an error that says "Run-time error 3073" operation must use an updateable query